# Can't target .net 3.5 after Windows update

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, windows-update

All of my builds broke after one of the updates this week. Now I can't change the target framework[image: I can't change the target framework]

and I can only choose 4.0 system assemblies[image: I can only choose 4.0 system assemblies]

Is there any way I can get around this without uninstalling all the latest updates? If I add the right version of the System dlls via browse, it uses hint paths, which means I will have to check the System dlls into git.

This has happened both on my machine and on our build machine after running Windows update, so that's the only thing I can guess caused the problem.

This is Windows 7 and seems to only apply to VS 2008. VS 2012 lets me change the framework and shows the correct path to the v2.0 System dlls.

Comment: The problem is only present in VS 2008. The only .NET related update installed this week was KB 2901983, .NET 4.5.2 for Windows 7 x64. All other recent updates are definition updates for MSE or security updates for Win7 x64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the [.NET Framework Targeting Pack page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/hh487283.aspx) for issues like this.

Basically, under Windows 8 you need to explicitly enable .NET 3.5 in "Windows Features". For earlier versions of Windows it just needs to be installed - the page has a link to the download.

Comment: Should these apply for Win 7 and VS 2008? Basically, everything worked earlier this week, and for years before, and now suddenly I can't change the framework target.

Comment: @DylanMusil: Not sure. I expected it was a Windows 8 issue, as when I answered you hadn't said anything about the version of VS or Windows. I suggest you *check* whether you've still got .NET 3.5 installed. (Do you *have* to still use VS2008? If VS2012 works, maybe this is a hint that it's worth using a more recent version of VS...)

Comment: It seems that VS 2008 is the outlier. It built fine in 2010. We are stuck on the older VS for some of our projects that require vdproj support. Thanks for your insight!

Comment: @DylanMusil: Does http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2014/04/17/visual-studio-installer-projects-extension.aspx help you?